# Condition to avoid duplicate insert in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, merge, duplicates

What I need to do

1. If the duplicate row exists, don't insert.
2. If the same party_num exists but other columns have different value, update the existing values of other columns for that party num.

What is the best way to do it since the source and target table has  over 500K records?

```
 INSERT INTO STAGING_CUST_ACCT

        SELECT 
            [CUSTOMER KEY]      AS [PARTY_NUM]
            ,[ACCOUNT CITY]             AS [PRIMARY CITY]
            ,[ACCOUNT STATE]            AS [PRIMARY STATE]
            ,[ACCOUNT ZIP]              AS [PRIMARY ZIP]
        FROM [RCC_CLOSED]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;
WITH changed_rows_only AS (
    SELECT [CUSTOMER KEY],[ACCOUNT CITY],[ACCOUNT STATE],[ACCOUNT ZIP] FROM RCC_CLOSED
    EXCEPT
    SELECT [PARTY_NUM]   ,[PRIMARY CITY],[PRIMARY STATE],[PRIMARY ZIP] FROM STAGING_CUST_ACCT
)
MERGE INTO STAGING_CUST_ACCT AS tgt
USING changed_rows_only AS src
ON (
  src.[CUSTOMER KEY] = tgt.[CUSTOMER KEY]
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
  tgt.[PRIMARY CITY]  = src.[ACCOUNT STATE]
 ,tgt.[PRIMARY STATE] = src.[ACCOUNT STATE]
 ,tgt.[PRIMARY ZIP]   = src.[ACCOUNT ZIP]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT(    [PARTY_NUM]   ,    [PRIMARY CITY],    [PRIMARY STATE],    [PRIMARY ZIP])
  VALUES(src.[CUSTOMER KEY],src.[ACCOUNT CITY],src.[ACCOUNT STATE],src.[ACCOUNT ZIP]);
```